# Use feedkeys then do command

Tags: command-line, plugin-fzf

I want to write a mapping that does `feedkeys(":cd " . getcwd())`, waits for me to edit the directory and then press enter, and then runs a command such as `:Rg` from the fzf plugin.

I tried doing this:

```
function! Rg_choose_dir()
    call feedkeys(":cd " . getcwd())
    :Rg
endfunction
```

but that has the effect of `:Rg` with the argument to `feedkeys` as the pattern. How can I get the behaviour I want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *might* be able to make this work with feedkeys, but it's usually hard/brittle to do so.

I would recommend using something `input(':cd ', getcwd(), 'dir')` to get the directory as input (with directory completion and `getcwd()` as the default), run the `cd`, and then do the `:Rg`:

```
execute 'cd' input(':cd ', getcwd(), 'dir')
Rg
```