# How do I call a user-defined command from a function, and wait until it finishes?

Tags: key-bindings, autocompletion, user-commands

The two functions in the script below can be called independently via key mappings `<leader>1` and `<leader>2`. In a perfect world, `<leader>1` will always be called first. If the user forgets to do that, I want `s:RunMe2nd()` to be helpful and call `s:RunMe1st()`. However, it needs to use the user-defined command to display the legal values and get the one that will be passed to the function.

After some tinkering, I was able to do that with `call feedkeys(":RunMe1st \<C-Z>", "t")`, but also I would like the execution of `s:RunMe2nd()` to be blocked until `:RunMe1st` finishes. Is that possible, and if so, how would I do it?

To see what I'm talking about, source the script, and then type `<leader>2`. You will see the pop-up menu for the completion items, but underneath it you'll also see an error saying `b:init` is undefined. `echomsg` doesn't wait for `feedkeys` to finish. Source the file again, and type `<leader>1` then `<leader>2` to see how it works when following the rules.

```
unlet! b:init   " Re-source this file to reset.

command! -buffer -nargs=1 -complete=customlist,<SID>LegalValues RunMe1st :call <SID>RunMe1st("<args>")
setlocal wildcharm=<C-Z>   " Used to open completion menu.
nnoremap <leader>1 :RunMe1st<space><C-Z>
nnoremap <leader>2 :call <SID>RunMe2nd()<CR>

function! s:LegalValues(ArgLead, CmdLine, CursorPos)
    return ["hello", "world", "42"]
endfunction

function! s:RunMe1st(arg)
    let b:init = a:arg
endfunction

function! s:RunMe2nd()
    if !exists("b:init")
        echomsg "You didn't run RunMe1st first. Let me help you."

        " How do I get Vim to wait for the next statement to finish?
        call feedkeys(":RunMe1st \<C-Z>", "t")
    endif
    echomsg "All good. You chose ".b:init
endfunction
```

Comment: Have a look at https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/28977/10604

Comment: That did it, @D. Ben Knoble. I wasn't aware that `input()` could use the same completion list as `:command`. That's a much better solution than using `feedkeys()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with after reading the link in @D. Ben Knoble's comment. The only thing I'm not terribly happy with is the `expand('<SID>')` workaround I used. It just seems like a bit of a hack, but it prevents the errors:

- `E120: Using <SID> not in a script context: s:LegalValues` or
- `E120: Using <SID> not in a script context: <SID>LegalValues`

```
unlet! b:init   " Re-source this file to reset.

command! -buffer -nargs=1 -complete=customlist,<SID>LegalValues RunMe1st :call <SID>RunMe1st("<args>")
setlocal wildcharm=<C-Z>   " Used to open completion menu.
nnoremap <leader>1 :RunMe1st<space><C-Z>
nnoremap <leader>2 :call <SID>RunMe2nd()<CR>

function! s:LegalValues(ArgLead, CmdLine, CursorPos)
    return ["hello", "world", "42"]
endfunction

function! s:RunMe1st(arg)
    let b:init = a:arg
endfunction

function! s:RunMe2nd()
    if !exists("b:init")
        echomsg "You didn't run RunMe1st first. Let me help you."
        let answer = input(':RunMe1st ',"\<C-Z>",'customlist,'.expand('<SID>').'LegalValues')
        call s:RunMe1st(answer)
    endif
    echomsg "All good. You chose ".b:init
endfunction
```

Comment: In `RunMe2nd`, why do you have `execute`? Would `call s:RunMe1st(answer)` not work? It looks like you wanted to quote the value of `answer`, would almost certainly fail if `answer` contained double-quotes.

Comment: I suppose you could also `execute 'RunMe1st' answer`

Comment: You're right. It does work. That must have been a remnant of my trial and error iterations. I'll edit to clear that up.